# ž is displayed bigger than other letters

Tags: html, css

I'm currently working in a website where some words contains č, ď, ň, ř, š, ž.
Unfortunately the special letters are displayed bigger than the normal letters.

Here an example: [image]

I use a .properties file where I include the text like this: [image]

Any ideas? I have another website with the same content but different cms and there it works well. CSS and font is the same for both sites.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The font your page is displayed in doesn't provide those - the browser and/or operating-system will be trying hard to provide sensible visuals for characters so they will draw on other fonts that do provide these characters. Try to find a webfont with all characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might find the CSS Unicode range facility useful.

If you have a font which has gaps, or in which you don’t like a certain character it is giving you, then you can change it for a character from a different font.

See for example https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face/unicode-range

> The unicode-range CSS descriptor sets the specific range of characters
> to be used from a font defined by @font-face and made available for
> use on the current page. If the page doesn't use any character in this
> range, the font is not downloaded; if it uses at least one, the whole
> font is downloaded.

Answer (score 2):

Find a webfont containing all required characters.
Of course this may be nearly impossible if you're expecting historians to enter [linear-b](https://decodeunicode.org/en/u+10000), [hieroglyphs](https://decodeunicode.org/en/u+13000) and other ancient and/or modern characters .. AFAIK there is **no font** covering all of UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

As already said, probably the used font doesn't contain that character, so the browser uses another font only for that letter, which can be different in actual size.

To avoid that, you should find a font that contains all the letters you need. I usually go to Googlefonts for that (https://fonts.google.com/) and there, at the top center, in the input field that is labeled "sentence" by default, type all the special characters needed (like `č ď ň ř š ž ü ä ß ©` etc.). This will display these characters with all the fonts listed. That way you can see if a font contains those (and how they look) or shows "?" or similar instead.

Comment: good tip +1 – not just the special ones though .. "I need ..." so you see they do match the font!

Comment: @flowtron Yes certainly. I usually also type some words which will appear often on the website, or the name of the client etc. to see what it will look like, plus the special characters I'll need, possibly in words that actually contain them